# Visual studio repeatedly asking for credentials where credentials are correct & working with other applications

Tags: windows, windows-7, visual-studio-2010

i am trying to get connect to my visual studio but its asking me for enter credential once i ask its again asking for credential  its going on in a loop i have been deleted my credential form windows credential manager and also done enable “System web browser” under Tools > Options > Environment > Accounts > Add and reauthenticate accounts using: dropdown. Then, sign in you accounts again but still i its showing again

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

in this case if your visual studio is asking you passward again and again than you can do one thing

1)Click on the Start button or press the Windows key.
2)Type "Credential Manager" in the search bar and press Enter.
3)find windows Credential Manager
4)find visual studio Credential Manager and clear it

1)Tools -> Options -> Accounts
2)In the “Add and reauthenticate accounts using:” dropdown, select “System web browser”
3)Sign out, then sign back in.
4)Restart Visual Studio
i tryed the second one and its worked